# How to get values from usercontrol & dynamic show usercontrol

Tags: wpf

It's might be a simple question, but I'm quite new in WPF and C#.

**My objective:**

1. Several usercontrols
2. Every usercontrol has a lot of chechboxes, textboxes;
3. Dynamically display usercontrols---only one of the usercontrols
   is displayed at one time;
4. Get values of the usercontrols from Mainwindow.

I have tried two methods:

```
1---MainWindow.XAML: local:myusercontrol name="myusercontrolinst" ;    
    Mainwindow.XAML.cs: string Result=myusercontrolinst.Value;    
2---MainWindow.XAML:contentcontrol name="mycontentcontrol";   
    Mainwindow.XAML.cs: mycontentcontrol.content=new myusercontrol();  myusercontrol mycontrol=new myusercontrol();  string Result=mycontrol.Value;
```

For method 1, I can access to the values of usercontrol, but cannot show usercontrol dynamically;
  For method 2, I can show usercontrol dynamically, but I cannot get the right value of usercontrol.

What's my problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of hard to follow your question. I think I have the gist of it though.

This is one way to do what I think you are asking. For simplicity, I only have one user control that I switch out. Press the UserControl 1/2 button to load the user control. Press the UserControl Value button to display the value (what is in the textbox).

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Name="btnUserControl1" Content="UserControl 1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Click="btnUserControl1_Click" />
            <Button Name="btnUserControl2" Content="UserControl 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Click="btnUserControl2_Click" />
            <Button Name="btnUserControlVal" Content="UserControl Value" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Click="btnUserControlVal_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="grid">
            <!-- This will hold the loaded user control -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        UserControl userControl = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void setUserControl(UserControl uc)
        {
            userControl = uc;
            grid.Children.Clear();
            grid.Children.Add(userControl);
        }

        private void btnUserControl1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
            uc.Label = "User Control 1";
            setUserControl(uc);
        }

        private void btnUserControl2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // I'm just reusing UserControl1, you would use a different user control here instead.
            UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
            uc.Label = "User Control 2";
            setUserControl(uc);
        }

        private void btnUserControlVal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (userControl != null)
            {
                // If you only have a few user controls then you could just check if it is each one, like this:
                if (userControl is UserControl1)
                {
                    UserControl1 uc = userControl as UserControl1;
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Value of user control is '{0}'.", uc.Value));
                }
                //else if (userControl is UserControl2)
                //{
                //    // ...
                //}

                // Or, you could make an interface and have each UserControl implement it
                //if (userControl is IMyInterface)
                //{
                //    IMyInterface uc = userControl as IMyInterface;
                //    string myVal = uc.GetValue();
                //    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Value of user control is '{0}'.", myVal));
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Content="{Binding Label}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Text="{Binding Value}" Name="textbox1" Margin="5" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public string Label
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
        }
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Label.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("Unspecified"));

        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is exactly what I want. And I'm moved by the comment in your code which is quite helpful for me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your are starting wit WPF you should learn to work with [The MV-VM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). What you want to do can be solved in a nice way using it:

1. First, you should have a MainViewModel, and a ViewModel for each different view that you want to show (as an UserControl).
2. In the main ViewModel you could have a property that represent the selected content (ViewModel) you are showing.
3. Then you should create a `DataTemplate` for each view model, in each one you can put your User Controls.
4. Finally in the Main Window create Content Control for showing the selected content.

This is an idea about a way for the implementation. Hope helps guide you to the right way...